# Reading all files in the Android file system

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am writing an Android mediaPlayer app, so I want to scan through all files on the entire phone (i.e. sdcard and phone memory). I can read from the sdcard, but not the root of it. That is, I can just read from the path `/sdcard/[folder]/` and it works fine, but if I go to `/sdcard/` the app crashes. How can I access all the files on the sdcard, as well as the files on the phone itself?

Comment: Are you aware of Androids Content Resolvers? Check this if you are not: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#viacontentresolver and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: that is helpful, but How will I call the next song from the mediaplayer instance?It only looks like we setDataSource() using the Uri, but I don't know how to see all songs in there

Comment: Actually I didn't work much with the whole media subsystem yet, so I'll pass this to someone else to answer. But this should be doable. I just wanted to make you aware, because scanning the whole sdcard/memory sounds like an unefficient, battery-wasting idea when all the files are already scanned for you. Edit: Just one idea for a search: You actually have to use a ContentResolver to query the media, the MediaPlayer is really only a player, it does not handle managing media, it just playes one piece of it. The links above explain that a bit more.

Comment: Further to the point made by @alextsc, Android has already gone to the trouble of reading all of the media files available and building a database of their metadata.  To be sure, it isn't perfect -- the last of Album Artist before Gingerbread, for example, but you should follow the link he provides and have a look at that before proceeding.

Comment: Get a list of Albums: `Cusor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Albums._ID, Albums.ALBUM}, null, null, Albums.ALBUM + " collate nocase")`  Get a list of an Album's MP3 Tracks, ordered by track number: `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media._ID, Media.TITLE, Media.ALBUM}, Media.ALBUM_ID + "=? and " + Media.MIME_TYPE + "=?", new String[] {albumid, "audio/mpeg"}, Media.TRACK)`

Comment: Here is a sample tutorial on the Android Dev Blog on how to make a sample music player which will retrieve all the music on a user's device, hope it helps: [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use the /sdcard/ path. it is not guaranteed to work all the time.

Use below code to get the path to sdcard directory.

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String rootPath= root.getPath();
```

From rootPath location, you can build the path to any file on the SD Card. For example if there is an image at /DCIM/Camera/a.jpg, then absolute path would be rootPath + "/DCIM/Camera/a.jpg".

However to list all files in the SDCard, you can use the below code

```
String listOfFileNames[] = root.list(YOUR_FILTER);
```

listOfFileNames will have names of all the files that are present in the SD Card and pass the criteria set by filter.

Suppose you want to list mp3 files only, then pass the below filter class name to list() function.

```
FilenameFilter mp3Filter = new FilenameFilter() {
File f;
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

        if(name.endsWith(".mp3")){
        return true;
        }

        f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name);

        return f.isDirectory();
    }
};
```

Shash