# How to scan for whole Android device and show available .csv files in a list view?

Tags: android, csv

I am creating a application where i want to put a feature like whenever user clicks on a button my **app scans for whole device and shows available .csv files** in a list view.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can't scan the whole device, only folders with the coresponding rights. For example sdcard.

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030446/reading-all-files-in-the-android-file-system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030446/reading-all-files-in-the-android-file-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // pass the path in method where you want to find .csv file

   public static File pathDcim = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());

public void getFile(pathDcim) 
{
        ArrayList<String> csvfile_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();       

        File dir = new File(path);
        Log.e("path ", "is " + path);
        File file[] = dir.listFiles();

        try {
            if (file.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                    if (file[i].isFile()) {
                        int mid =                        file[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");



    String ext = file[i].getName().substring(mid + 1,
                                file[i].getName().length());
                        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("csv")) 
                        {
                            //System.out.println((file[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                            //System.out.println((file[i].lastModified()));
                            csvfile_arraylist.add(file[i].getAbsolutePath());

                        }
                    } else {

                        if (!file[i].getAbsolutePath().toString().contains("/.")) 
                        {
                            getFile(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.e("ignored path-->","-->" + file[i].getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // get images form dcim folder
```